# How deal with special characters in GET request for a password field?

Tags: java, get, character, encode

I'm working in a web app that authenticates through a get request (and I have no other option), the method already works, except for users whose password contains special characters, for example there is a password that is: *cHara*. If the user and password  combination is correct the response is a json with some information, else I get a json with {valid:0}, here the code:

```
        url = new URL("http://www.secret.url.com.co");
        String RESOURCE = "/authLdap/";
        String pass = URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
        tUrl = new URL(url + RESOURCE + "?usuario=" + usuario + "&clave=" + pass);
        HttpURLConnection req;
        req = (HttpURLConnection) tUrl.openConnection();
        req.setDoOutput(true);
        req.setRequestMethod("GET");
        req.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));
```

How should I encode pass?

Comment: What sits on the remote side? Does it know it has to URLDecode what it gets?

Comment: Over the remote side I not have control. Actually I know that the password works because more deep is a LDAP authentication, that is in other pages that use the LDAP directly the password works, but for me and my application permissions are limited and not have access to LDAP directly only through this url.

Comment: If a print encode pass the result is \*cHacra\*, I mean it's the same.

Comment: OK, by "special characters" you mean an asterisk and not some more exotic characters like an german umlaut? If so then maybe the remote webservice is doing some filtering on its input and discarding '*' characters. As you seem to use some sort of an LDAP auth and the asterisk has a special meaning there this seams reasonable. But i'm just guessing now. Can you tell any further infos about the auth-service?

Comment: Yes I mean asterisk, is the unique case that I know, the organization have a LDAP directory, but I have no control over this, who helped me to achieve my requirement is a friend that have access credentials for directory, now he is not available, probably the problem is easy of solve from the other side, but the urgency is pressing.
According to my understanding, and your comments seems that the problem is that the petition is omitting the *, either or lack of decoded step or for a incorrect filter. Now, is there a trick for make that symbol pass throught without be eliminated?

Comment: Other systems, programmed by others that use the ldap directly can log in with this problematic password, I checked that. Ergo the problem is in my code, or in the remote side,the ldap can deal with *.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP-escape your input before URLEncoding it. The asterisk has a special meaning in LDAP (match-any) and maybe the remote auth-service isn't doing proper escaping.

More infos can be found here: http://blog.dzhuvinov.com/?p=585